# Is there any alternative of Sql server Agent on Sql Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

I want to run the sql Agent job that would processed my data from the server on regular basis and save it to another table. Is there any way to schedule the job on Sql Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Automation provides a great cloud-based alternative to SQL Agent.  Please see [Azure Automation: Your SQL Agent in the Cloud](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/26/azure-automation-your-sql-agent-in-the-cloud/) and [Truncate table in SQL DB if DB is approaching max size](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Azure-Automation-Your-SQL-30f8736b).